# How can I know request waiting time in Nginx Ingress Controller?

Tags: nginx, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

We use **Kubernetes** with **Nginx Ingress Controller** to run our platform with various backend services. We also use New Relic (& Prometheus, Grafana) for our Observability dashboards & alerts. Nginx Ingress Controller is the entrypoint for all our requests.

As we keep getting requests, if all threads of our Backend services are busy, then I am assuming that the requests start getting queued up and they get eventually serviced as the threads / resources start freeing up.

**Currently, I am unable to find a metric that will give me the amount of time requests are waiting before being picked up by Nginx and eventually being serviced by our Backend.**

Nginx Ingress Controller **Prometheus metrics** contain the following 4 latency metrics:

- `nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds` (nginx var:
  `request_time`)
- `nginx_ingress_controller_response_duration_seconds`
  (nginx var: `upstream_response_time`)
- `nginx_ingress_controller_connect_duration_seconds` (nginx var:
  `upstream_connect_time`)
- `nginx_ingress_controller_header_duration_seconds` (nginx var:
  `upstream_header_time`)

On plotting these metrics and trying various load tests, I have figured out that all of these metrics are giving me the latency of requests once they are picked up by Nginx but none of them seem to include the waiting time of requests before being picked up by Nginx.

I am looking for answers to the following questions:

- Does `upstream_connect_time` include the waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)?
- Does any of the above 4 metrics include the waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)?
- I have found a variable called `upstream_queue_time` in `ngx_http_upstream_module` mentioned [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_queue_time). Does this metric give me waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)? If so, is this available only for Nginx Plus and which metric can I use?
- Is there any other way I can get insight into the waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)?

Please let me know if my above understanding is incorrect.

You time and expertise in answering this is really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, according to the `epoll` model in Nginx and its `asynchronous`/`non-blocking` nature, there's no such waiting time for a request to be picked up by Nginx.

A request comes in, Nginx processes it, transferring it to an upstream immediately, or putting it in the **upstream queue** if an upstream server cannot be selected immediately. The time it spent in the queue is defined in $variable `upstream_queue_time` in ngx_http_upstream_module, as you have found.

Other 4 typical built‑in timing variables are as follows,

- **$request_time** – Full request time, starting when NGINX reads the first byte from the client and ending when NGINX sends the last byte of the response body
- **$upstream_connect_time** – Time spent establishing a connection with an upstream server
- **$upstream_header_time** – Time between establishing a connection to an upstream server and receiving the first byte of the response header
- **$upstream_response_time** – Time between establishing a connection to an upstream server and receiving the last byte of the response body

To answer your questions:

> Does upstream_connect_time include the waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)?

No.

> Does any of the above 4 metrics include the waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)?

Yes. **$request_time** covers all the time from when a request comes in and a response sent out.

> I have found a variable called upstream_queue_time in ngx_http_upstream_module mentioned here. Does this metric give me waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)? If so, is this available only for Nginx Plus and which metric can I use?

The metric gives you the waiting time of requests spent in the **upstream queue**.

> Is there any other way I can get insight into the waiting time of requests (before being picked up by Nginx)?

Normally you only get the Nginx processing time (inbound + outbound) by subtraction (**$request_time** - **$upstream_response_time**)

Correct me if I'm wrong.